# Duplicates when doing select in a database and showing it in a table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Actually i'm new in ASPX and VB.net and i'm trying to show certain items for specific user in a table, so firstly i check and put in a list the "software" which a user has purchased and it looks like this in database:

table_username: User1 table_codesoftware: VP or table_username: User2 table_codesoftware: VP and table_username User2 table_codesoftware VPO.

So User1 has access just to software which has VP in the database as software code when User2 has access to software VP and VPO.

But when i'm trying to show items for User2 it shows two times the software with code VP.

Here is my VB.NET code where i'd a SELECT where aggiornamenti is the table where there are all the softwares and dat("codesw_cs") is the list with available for user softwares.

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim result As New ArrayList()
    Dim table As New StringBuilder()

    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT codesw_cs FROM clienti_sw WHERE nomeutente_cs = '" + Context.User.Identity.Name + "'"

    Dim SQLConnect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(SQLConnect)

    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, con)

    Try
        table = New StringBuilder()
        con.Open()


        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()

            Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For count As Integer = 0 To (reader.FieldCount - 1)
                dict.Add(reader.GetName(count), reader(count))
            Next


            result.Add(dict)
        End While
        reader.Close()

        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can't load Web page" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try

    For Each dat As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In result
        con.Open()
        Dim msd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM aggiornamenti WHERE softcode_ag = '" + dat("codesw_cs") + "'", con)

        reader = msd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            table.Append("<tr>")
            table.Append("<td>").Append(reader.GetString("nomesoftware_ag")).Append("</td>")
            table.Append("<td>").Append(reader.GetString("version_ag")).Append("</td>")
            table.Append("<td>").Append(Date.Parse(reader.GetString("releasedata_ag")).ToShortDateString).Append("</td>")
            table.Append("<td>").Append("<a href=""" + reader.GetString("download_ag") + """ aria-disabled=""true"">Download</a></td>")
            table.Append("</tr>")

        End While
        placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(table.ToString))

        reader.Close()

        con.Close()


    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: There's a few things that could happen. Does the query ever return duplicate? Do you properly clear the table variable? Can the For Each loop ever create duplicate entry? You could figure it out by putting a breakpoint. Right now, on the second loop of the For Each, the "table" variable would still contain the values of the previous loop.

Comment: @the_lotus Actually i've yet done a debug and the point is that in the 1st For the dat("codesw_cs") is VP and in the while it's add the right items and even in the second For cycle the dat value is VPO and it's add just items for VPO and exit from the for so i can't get where it duplicate's it..

Comment: @the_lotus i've just added the whole code from Page_load

Comment: Put "table = New StringBuilder()" inside the For Each

Comment: @the_lotus damn that works... but i can't get why, i mean doesn't the table variable will be clean from the 1st dat value as the For loop is done by a second time? Make an answer so i'll accept it

Comment: Variable don't clean themselves unless you ask them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the table variable on each loop. If not, the second time it loop, it will continue to append to the variable.

```
For Each dat As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In result
  table = New StringBuilder()
```

Comment: One more think, am i doing a correct approach by making the table in this way as i'm new in VB?

Comment: @JohnKarry that is subjective, some might use DataGrid or Repeater instead. But first, use parameters instead of appending your variable to the query. Then, handle the case of string that could contain html/javascript (ex: what if omesoftware contains <).